# How to stop docker-compose run command

Tags: docker-compose

I'm using a node docker with a simple aplication created with strongloop I want start arc `slc arc` instead the default command `slc run`

my app is called `app` in the docker-compose.yml file, I run the following command

```
$ docker-compose run app slc run
```

Arc starts but I can't stop the command, I've tried `CTRL + C`

Answer (score 4):

You might need to add the following lines to your docker-compose file since you're running it in the foreground:

```
tty: true
stdin_open: true
```

This will send the signal to the container application instead.

If that doesn't work, I would just run the application as a daemon using the -d flag.

```
docker-compose run app slc run -d
```

You can stop or kill using:

```
docker-compose stop
docker-compose kill
docker stop [container names]
docker kill [container names]
```

Running the docker-compose commands will stop or kill all of the running containers, you can add individual container names after the command if you only want to kill individual containers.